# MyBatis work with dynamic queries, such as count(*) or data in a new column

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, mybatis

Lets assume I have user_partner_table

```
id, user_id, partner_id, app_completed, user_name, partner_name
1, 2345, 232, t, sam, A&C Bank
2, 2345, 121, f, sam, M&M Bank
3, 4324, 123, t, tom, DC Bank
4, 4324, 121, t, tom, M&M Bank
5, 1211, 134, f, harry, USBank
6, 1211, 111, t, harry, creditunion
```

In my DAO Class I have getters and setters for id, user_id, partner_id, app_completed, user_name, partner_name

If I want to get any of the data based on the columns that are available I can write a query and in the query make `resultType="UserPartnerDAO"` and have results as `ArrayList<UserPartnerDAO>`.

But what if I want to run query which generate different data column with aggregate data. Example:

Let say I was user_id, `count_of_app_completed` basically how many applications each user has completed, so its a `group by`. Now there is no column name `"count_of_app_completed"`
so if I put following query in my UserPartnerMapper.xml

```
<select id="aggregateQuery" resultType="UserPartnerDAO">
  SELECT user_id,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 END) count_of_app_completed
    FROM user_partner_table
GROUP BY user_id
</select>
```

What how do I get access to the dynamic column?, also at the same time 
How can I get access to all the columns? 
Is it correct to set resultType as "`UserPartnerDAO`" or should the result type be something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `bean` (`class`) that maps to the data in the aggregated query.

Depending on specifically what else you're using your `UserPartnerDAO` class for, you could sneak the field in there. As long as it has a getter/setter aliased to `count_of_app_completed`, *MyBatis* will be happy. Depending on what else you're using that class for, it's possible some other things will not be happy about the extra field. (And from a general code organization standpoint, it's a bit messy.)

In that case -- and what I often do -- you can create a specific class just to hold the results from that query (or perhaps a few different fields if you have a few different types of queries). *Mybatis* simply needs a place to store the information -- that is, an object with the right getters and setters. It doesn't matter (to *Mybatis*) if not all of them apply to that specific query.

Similarly, I'll sometimes create, say, an `InputBean` class to store the various items I may need within a query to dynamically interleave with it (i.e. the name of a table or  `LIMIT` value to be used in the query). I may use that same `InputBean` object in multiple queries, and only use some of the members in each case.